# Is there a way to reprogram the thinkvantage button to assign a shell bash program to it?

Tags: bash, scripts, shortcuts

Is there a way to reprogram the lenovo think vantage button to open and run a shell bash program on ubuntu 14.04 lts?

I have tried system preferences > keyboard >shortcuts > custom

and assigned a short cut to that button and it still doesn’t work

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`xbindkeys` should be able to do this. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Now run:

```
xbindkeys -k
```

and press the think vantage button.  Your output should look something like:

```
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.
"NoCommand"
    m:0x0 + c:159
    NoSymbol
```

Now create a file named `.xbindkeysrc` in your home directory:

```
touch ~/.xindkeysrc
```

open the file in your favourite editor and add:

```
"bash /path/to/your/script.sh"
m:0x0 + c:159
```

Replacing `m:0x0 + c:159` with whatever you got from your output earlier.

If you want a terminal window to open replace the first line with:

```
"gnome-terminal -e './path/to/script.sh"
```

Log out/back in or reboot for the changes to take effect.

(re)sources: [ThinkWiki: ThinkPad Button](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Button)

Comment: It dos not work it will not let me run it at 'xbindkeys-k'

Comment: @Jhondoe Can you be more specific? What happens exactly?

Comment: I found away around that problem and have folwed the rest of your instructions but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Jhondoe Doesn't work isn't specific enough. Please upload your xbindkeysrc to paste.ubuntu.com and link it here so I can see. Thanks!

Comment: The file is empty apart from what you said to upload

Comment: @Jhondoe Can I see the exact file please?

Comment: "bash server6" m:0x0 + c:159

Comment: @Jhondoe Yes, that's not going to work. You need to specify the exact path to `server6` and include any extensions (if it has one). For example, if the file is on your desktop you'd put: `bash /home/jhondoe/Desktop/server6`.

Comment: ThAt still does not work

Comment: Please post the entire contents of the file again and the exact location and name the file is at. Does it have executable permissions?

Comment: The file"bash /home/jhondoe/server6" m:0x0 + c:159 it is at /home/jhondoe/

Comment: @Jhondoe and your user on the machine is named jhondoe? You need to replace jhondoe with the name of your user on the computer. Or I guess `"bash ~/server6"` would work.

Comment: I had already had it at he right name I changed it to post on here

Comment: @Jhondoe Hmm, that's a bit odd then. I don't have a ThinkPad but it *should* work. You've rebooted right? Try running `xbindkeys` in a terminal and then try pressing the key. You're sure your script works right? Trying to rule things out here. `m:0x0 + c:159` is the correct key?

Comment: I have rebooted and that is the right key

Comment: Does it work now then?

Comment: Did you try running `xbindkeys` in a terminal and then pressing? If that doesn't work than I am rather at a loss. If you run `xev -event keyboard` and then press the key what does it output?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something has changed for the better on Xubuntu 18 Xfce 4.12.

I was able to assign a script to the ThinkVantage-button on a T420 from the built-in Keyboard control panel. Did not install any additional software.

[image: Screenshot here of the Keyboard settings for Thinkpad button]

The ThinkVantage button has shortcut "XF86Launch1" - it was ridiculously simple. Now I can toggle touchpad on/off with the Thinkpad button. Sweet.